# Java CardLayout not displaying

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, cardlayout

I have a game that already runs and works and I want to add a title screen to it. I'm trying to add a CardLayout for easy switching between game and titlescreen. My current issue is that nothing is being displayed. Here is an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AooMO.png . I simply get a blank JPanel when I run it. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class UI
{
private static JPanel cards;
private static CardLayout cardLayout;

public static void main(String args[])
    {new UI();}

public UI()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Scrolling Shooter");

    frame.setResizable(false);
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();  
    int width = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());  
    int height = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight());  
    frame.setSize(width, height);

    TitleScreen title = new TitleScreen(frame);
    ScrollingShooter game = new ScrollingShooter(frame);

    cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    cards.add(title, "title");
    cards.add(game, "game");
    cards.setOpaque(true);
    frame.getContentPane().add(cards);

    cardLayout = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();
    cardLayout.first(cards);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * Switches to the next screen
 */
public static void nextScreen()
    {cardLayout.next(cards);}

/**
 * Returns to the first screen
 */
public static void firstScreen()
    {cardLayout.first(cards);}
}
```

Comment: Thanks to @MadProgrammer its all working now. I start my title screen and then move to the game. The only issue is my game is not registering keys but thats probably because I have my title screen using a keylistener. Not sure if I should try to fix this error here or make a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added `Cards` to anything.

Try adding `Cards` to frame and then make the frame visible

For example...

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Scrolling Shooter");

TitleScreen title = new TitleScreen(frame);
ScrollingShooter game = new ScrollingShooter(frame);

cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
cards.add(title, "title");
cards.add(game, "game");
cards.setOpaque(true);

cardLayout = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();
cardLayout.first(cards);

frame.add(cards);
//...
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setSize(width, height);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

FYI: You should come `setResizable` before setting the frame size as `setResizable` can change the frames border insets

Comment: Please don't post code or a stack trace in a comment.  It is more easily readable in a question.  As to the question, an NPE is a separate question to 'no change in cards'.

Comment: Sounds like you have a problem with one of your classe trying to load images, which isn't shown in the above question